# Backbone.js: Collection containing multiple Models with same ID

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I've a merged collection in Backbone which contains photos and albums.

To distinguish between them, i've added a field `type` which is either `photo` or `album`. When I populate the collection, I create different models within the `Collection#model` method

```
  model: (attrs, options) ->
    switch attrs.type
      when 'album' then new App.Models.Album(attrs, options)
      when 'photo' then new App.Models.Photo(attrs, options)
```

Now I've discoverd a strange bug where adding a photo and an album with the same ID (let's say `2`) results in a merge.

I've tracked this down to [these](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L682) LOC in the source code. It seems that it's undoable without creating a fork of Backbone itself. I've tried it but it also [fails 35 tests](http://cloud.philippspiess.com/PPIa).

I thought of 4 different ways of doing this, I don't know which of them is the better one:

1. I could add a prefix to the id. Let's say `photo_2`. This causes a change in the backend as well as some changes in the frontend to don't hit the server at `/photos/photo_2`
2. I could fork Backbone and [change these](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L682) LOC.
3. I could create two separate collections but have to deal with a merge and a sort in the view (which effects clients performance and requires a rewriting of the backend)
4. I could start with a photo ID of, let's say `1000000`. This would extremely decrease the probability that a given user which has uploaded a photo with a given ID has also created an album with the same ID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since version 1.2 you can use [`Collection.modelId`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-137) to specify how your collection will uniquely identify models. In your case, you can do the following to ensure that your types have different IDs.

```
  var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    modelId: function (attrs) {
      return attrs.type + "-" + attrs.id;
    }
    // ...
  })
```

Comment: Is there a way of getting the model as an argument here rather than just its attributes?

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest that on both Album and Photo, you add the following:

```
  idAttribute: 'uniqueId'
  parse: function(response) {
    response.uniqueId = type+'_'+response.id
    return response;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`idAttribute:'uniqueId'`

if this uniqueId is not known while declaring, try

`idAttribute:'UUID'`

I generated one from https://www.uuidgenerator.net/ and put it here, this attribute defined here need not be in model, so I just put in a UUID.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer so it's a little more clear, and perhaps add a code example?